# how to get data's from sqlite in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the data in the android(Sqlite Database).How to transfer this database data's to the System Database( like Access or SQL Server).After Transfer this data's i have to use the data in the System.I am new to android. Can anyone help me.

Note:
If the android device have the Database db1.I wish to use the db1 data in the Desktop Application .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the database file to the desktop, and then open it there with SQLite. You could then export the data to CSV file, and import this one in the database of your choice.

Comment: Thanks For your Help,Thomas Mueller.

Answer (score 0):

The db file is present in "/data/app/" Your Application Package directory "/databases/" Your DB File.

Copy the file from this location and use the steps provided by Thomas Mueller.